# Set default (initial) value for descriptor

Tags: python, object, properties, instance, descriptor

Assume we got the following code:

```
class NonNegative():
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return instance.__dict__[self.name]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value

class Person:
    fingerCount = NonNegative()
    eyesCount = NonNegative()
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

p = Person("name")
print(p.fingerCount)    <----- I want a default value printed here, instead of a KeyError
print(p.eyesCount)      <-----                 ------ | | ------
```

How would I go about assigning a default (initial) value for fingerCount and eyesCount respectively?

So that I don't have to do:

```
p = Person("name")
p.fingerCount = 10
p.eyesCount = 2
print(p.fingerCount)  # output: 10   
print(p.eyesCount)    # output: 2
```

, but instead just can do:

```
p = Person("name")
print(p.fingerCount)  # output: 10   
print(p.eyesCount)    # output: 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass a default value to the `__init__` method, which saves it for use when `instance.__dict__[self.name]` doesn't yet exist.

```
class NonNegative():
    def __init__(self, v=0):  # You may or may not want a default default value
        self.dflt = v

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return instance.__dict__.get(self.name, self.dflt)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value
```

```
class Person:
    fingerCount = NonNegative(10)
    eyesCount = NonNegative(2)
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

If you like, you can subclass `NonNegative` to provide use-case-specific defaults.

```
class FingerCount(NonNegative):
    def __init__(self, v=10):
        super().__init__(v)


class EyeCount(NonNegative):
    def __init__(self, v=2):
        super().__init__(v)


class Person:
    fingerCount = FingerCount()
    eyecount = EyeCount()


class Cyclops(Person):
    eyecount = EyeCount(1)
```

If you want a per-instance starting value for a property, initialize the property via its setter in `__init__` like any other attribute.

```
class Person:
    fingerCount = NonNegative()
    eyesCount = NonNegative()

    def __init__(self, fcount=10, ecount=2):
        self.fingerCount = fcount
        self.eyesCount = ecount
```

Comment: You know, I actually thought about that, but I didn't think it would work due to the fact that all instances of the Person class shares the same instance of the NonNegative descriptor. [See descriptors2.py here (the typical gotcha)](https://realpython.com/python-descriptors/)

Comment: **Question:** Since all instances of the Person class shares the same NonNegative descriptor instance, how is it possible to have different "self.dflt" values?!

Comment: You don't, which isn't an issue as long as you are dealing with immutable defaults. The default value is only used when the underlying attribute doesn't yet exist in the instance dictionary, and as such is by definition something that's part of the property, not the instance via which the property is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

for a more static hard-coded solution

```
class NonNegative:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        if isinstance(instance, Person) and instance.__dict__.get('fingerCount') is None:
            instance.fingerCount = 10
        if isinstance(instance, Person) and instance.__dict__.get('eyesCount') is None:
            instance.eyesCount = 2
        return instance.__dict__[self.name]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value

class Person:
    fingerCount = NonNegative()
    eyesCount = NonNegative()
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

p = Person("name")
print(p.fingerCount)
print(p.eyesCount)
# 10
# 2
```